# Remove в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Не получается удалить объект.

```
funcDelete = (e) => {
e.target.remove()
}    

<div onClick="(e) => funcDelete"><span>Teet</span></div>
```

Мне надо всегда удалять div, но кликнув на span, удаляется именно span. Как правильно написать, чтобы при клике на span и div полностью удалялся элемент div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вариант можно сделать так:

```js
del = (e) => e.remove();
```

```css
div {display: inline-block; margin: 5px; border: 2px solid orange; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div onclick="del(this)"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div onclick="del(this)"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div onclick="del(this)"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div onclick="del(this)"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div onclick="del(this)"><span>Teet</span></div>
```

Или так (заодно, если вы собираетесь дать им класс для стиля, можно будет уже и не заморачиваться с onclick="..."):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('moo')].forEach( 
  (e) => e.addEventListener('click', () => e.remove() )
);
```

```css
.moo {display: inline-block; margin: 5px; border: 2px solid orange; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="moo"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div class="moo"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div class="moo"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div class="moo"><span>Teet</span></div>
<div class="moo"><span>Teet</span></div>
```

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME скажите пожалуйста если я клик по 1 элементу удаляется последний или я где-то ошибся ?

Comment: @Leks , удаляется тот, по которому кликнули... настолько быстро, что невозможно заметить) Если в функцию добавить второй аргумент (index), он будет указывать на номер элемента — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/4yxpeu03/ , здесь нагляднее.

Comment: В react приложении почему то пишет, что: 
TypeError: e.remove is not a function

Comment: Сработало с e.target.parentNode.remove()